# I have a problem with $v(x, y)=2xy+ λy$

Tags: complex-analysis

> $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $v(x, y)=2 x y+ \lambda y$. Determine for which value of $\lambda$ a function $u(x, y)$ exists such that $$f(x+iy) =u(x, y) +iv(x, y) $$ is holomorphic. If this is possible find $u(x, y)$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(i) =1.$

**Solution**

$v(x, y)=2xy+ \lambda y$.  I use the rule $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$, so we have $v_x=2y$ and $v_y=2x+ \lambda$, and so we can write  $u_x=2x+ \lambda$  and $u_y=-2y$ and later $u_{xx} +u_{yy} =2-2=0 $.  Hence it is holomorphic, this is possible, but this means that $\lambda$ is any number $\in \mathbb R$??

And later, when I calculate, I got $v(x, y) =(2x+1)y+c(x)$ and $v(x, y) =-2yx+c(y)$.

But how to show that $f(0)=0$ and $f(i) =1$?

Comment: Do you mean that $\lambda \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: This is my question

Comment: Because calculating derivtives i cant find vaule λ

Answer (score 1):

Use Cauchy-Riemann equations.

[image]

Using

[image]

The results are:

[image]

Integrate to find u(x,y)

[image]

Now we have

[image]

Recall the two values f(0)=0 and f(i)=1

For the f(0)=0 case this implies that x=0 and y=0.

In this case it is true, but there is no lambda to be recovered.

For the f(i)=1 case this implies that x=0 and y=1.

Lambda can be recovered here. Consider the following:

[image]

Solving for lambda we find that

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Your solution was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating the Cauchy-Riemann equations gives

$$u(0,y)=c -y^2$$

and then

$$u(x,y)=u(0,y)+x^2+\lambda x=c-y^2+x^2+\lambda x$$

Finally, for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$,

$$u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=x^2-y^2+\lambda x+ 2ixy +i\lambda y +c$$

or, equivalently, for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, $f(z)=z^2+\lambda z +c$.

So, $f(0)=0\Longleftrightarrow c=0$  and $f(i)=1\Longleftrightarrow -1+\lambda i= 1 \Longleftrightarrow \lambda=\frac{2}{i}=-2i$.